# Vue component parent from child recursive include

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, components

So I want to have many components nested to each other and included dynamically.

Lets assume simple case:

`-container
  -row
   -container
    -row 
     -widget`

etc.

So how can I include container that will load row which will load previous component container in an elegant way (recursive I guess)

I want this functionality for more components than just `container` and `row`

Comment: I want to bubble down with `data` as I am including tree based json.

Comment: this could be useful https://alligator.io/vuejs/recursive-components/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem myself right now:
it's usually webpack which cause this problem so you have two options:

1. Register your component Globally
2. On you child component, register the parent like this:

   components: {
   ComponentLoader: () => import('./ComponentLoader.vue')
   }

you can read more here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components

Answer (score 0):

So to achieve my goal I have to build ComponentLoader and child components loaded from it.

```
ComponentLoader.vue
<template
    v-for="(block, index) in data.children">
    <component
      v-if="component"
      :is="component"
      :key="`container-${block.id}-${index}`"
      :data="block"/>
  </template>
</template>
```

Which for instance will load Article component from its children:

```
ArticleComponent.vue
<template>
  <SimpleArticle
    :data="data"/>
  <ComponentLoader
    v-if="data.children"
    :data="data"/>
</template>
```

So `ArticleComponent` will call `ComponentLoader` again if it has more children to load. This way works for me and is recursively going through the data tree.